# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fsdecode'; PYTHON 2.7; mac os X

Tags: python-2.7, terminal, macos-high-sierra

I have found a script in PYTHON. Need to run it to cut images' sizes.
Why this error occurs and How to fix it?
(Python 2.7 installed+ installed PIL for current script+ Imaging 1.1.7; Mac OS)

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import os
from PIL import Image

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--image_dir', help='Directory of images to resize')
args = parser.parse_args()

image_dir = os.getcwd() + "/" + args.image_dir

for f in os.listdir(image_dir):
    filename = os.fsdecode(f)
    image = Image.open(image_dir + '/' + filename)
    print(image_dir + '/' + filename)
    height, width = image.size
    if width > 1000:
        resize_amt = 1000 / width
        new_height = int(round(height * resize_amt))
        image = image.resize((new_height, 1000))
        image.save(os.getcwd() + "/" + image_dir + "/" + filename)
```

After I've fixed all issues this text occurs in Terminal:

> Oleksandrs-MacBook-Air: jaskier$ python resize.py --image_dir=/Images/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "resize.py", line 16, in 
>       filename = os.fsdecode(f)
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fsdecode'

Comment: It says that the ‘os’ module has no function ‘fsdecode’

Comment: This could mean that you are using a version of python that does not have fsdecode in os module ...

Comment: python --version
Python 2.7.10

Already tried to install 3.6, but system PATH is overwritten by 2.7 -_-

Comment: Hmmm, try doin python3 —version

Comment: *Have installed 3.6.4 manually from https://www.python.org/downloads/
Result:
Last login: Sat Mar 24 14:25:50 on ttys000
Oleksandrs-MacBook-Air:~ jaskier$ python --version
Python 2.7.10

Comment: Yes but the command python defaults to your system version; if you try to specify the command ‘python3’ maybe itll work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Hugh difference between Python 2.7(native for Mac OS) and Python 3+(should install with terminal or https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/

Terminal:

```
pip3 install Pillow
```

It will help to make dependencies between PIL and Python3... (moreover check Python3 in folder:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/
>   The pip3 should be also there if you've done all correctly.

After this steps now I have some code errors, but none of modules errors. I hope it will help someone.